# How can I distinguish a winner in this thread race?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been writing a race code for a class I am in that races two threads, a tortoise and a hare. I can get both of them to run for 80 units but I don't know how to write a code that determines and outputs who the winner is. Any help would be appreciated because I am super new to coding.

I have the tortoise, hare, and raceParticipant classes. My driver class looks like this, where I would assume I put the winner code?

```
package Domain;

public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        Hare bob = new Hare();
        Tortoise fred = new Tortoise();
        int winDistance = 80;

        do {
            bob.sprint();
            fred.sprint();


            bob.display();
            fred.display();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }while(bob.getTotalDistance() < winDistance && fred.getTotalDistance() < winDistance);



}
}
```

My sprint method is

```
public int sprint()

{
    int sleep = generator.nextInt(100);
    int sprintDistance = 0;
    if (sleep > sleepPercent)
    {
        sprintDistance = generator.nextInt(topSpeed) + 1;
    }

    totalDistance +=sprintDistance;
    return sprintDistance;
}
```

Comment: When would you loop end?

Comment: Unless there's some thread creation going on in `.sprint()`, you only have one thread.

Comment: @Summer - is your instructor expecting you to actually use threads and synchronization primitives.  Or is this just a simple exercise that simulates two objects running?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see you creating a new thread anywhere.

You can create a `Hare` class like this:

```
public class Hare implements Runnable {

    private static final int SLEEP_DURATION = 3000; //milliseconds
    private static final int SPEED = 3; //units per second

    private int distanceToRun;
    private final RaceFinishListener listener;

    public Hare(int distanceToRun, RaceFinishListener listener) {
        this.distanceToRun = distanceToRun;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        do {
            distanceToRun -= SPEED;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_DURATION);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (distanceToRun > 0);
        listener.onRaceFinished(getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

and a similar `Tortoise` class with these variables:

```
private static final int SLEEP_DURATION = 1000; //sleeps less
private static final int SPEED = 1; //but is slow
```

Then create a *listener* to get notified when someone has finished:

```
public interface RaceFinishListener {
    void onRaceFinished(String finisher);
}
```

and finally your main class:

```
public class Test implements RaceFinishListener {

    private String winner;
    private static final int DISTANCE_TO_RUN = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().race();
    }

    private void race() {
        Hare bob = new Hare(DISTANCE_TO_RUN, this);
        Tortoise fred = new Tortoise(DISTANCE_TO_RUN, this);

        new Thread(bob).start();
        new Thread(fred).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRaceFinished(String finisher) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (winner == null) {
                winner = finisher;
                System.out.println(finisher + " is the winner!");
            } else {
                System.out.println(finisher + " lost.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

> Tortoise is the winner!
>   Hare lost.

Comment: You're right. My professor referred to this as threading, but as I am finding out in my search to try and solve this problem, it isn't threads I am running for the race, just threads to sleep.

Comment: @Summer ok, you can look at other answers then. I'll leave this answer here just in case it can help someone else. :)

Answer (score 0):

After this line:

```
    }while(bob.getTotalDistance() < winDistance && fred.getTotalDistance() < winDistance);
```

You would just have:

```
   boolean bobWins = (bob.getTotalDistance() >= winDistance);
   boolean fredWins = (fred.getTotalDistance() >= winDistance);

   if (bobWins && fredWins) {
      System.out.println("It's a tie");
   }
   else if (bobWins) {
      System.out.println("Bob Wins");
   }
   else {
       System.out.println("Fred Wins");
   }
```

Comment: This was it. I definitely think I had the concept or threads wrong from what I interpreted from class so I was looking at the wrong information to try and solve it.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, don't forget to upvote and/or accept it.